# Should you free pointers that reference already allocated data?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm aware that pointers that point to `malloc`-ed data need to be freed where appropriate.
For example:

```c
Item* items = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item) * 1);
```

^ when I'm done with this, I'd have to free it. Makes sense.

However, consider the following struct:

```c
typedef struct Items {
    Vector* fruits;
} Items;
```

where `Vector` is:

```c
typedef struct Vector {
    void** data;
    int size;
 } Vector;
```

Assume I've allocated memory for the `Items` struct and the `Vector` member contains, say, 3 items (of another struct `Boxes`).

If I were to have a `Boxes` pointer variable that references the *second member* of the Vector in the `Items` struct, would that need to be freed after usage?

```c
// Does `box1` need to be explicitly freed?
Boxes* box1 = items->fruits[1]; // `items` is of type `Items`
```

I understand that that variable `box1` wasn't explicitly heap-allocated. Do *only* heap-allocated pointers need to be freed?

Comment: You don't free *pointers*, you free *allocations*.

Comment: No. You need to free what you allocated (e.g. the array of boxes), and attempting to free an individual Box would be incorrect.

Comment: If this question is about C++ then the answer is RAII. If this question is about C then remove the C++ tag

Comment: Only release stuff you own. If you don't know where it came from, or how it was allocated, don't <expletive deleted> with it.

Comment: Anything returned by `malloc` (and relatives) must eventually be freed using `free`.

Comment: Given `malloc` and `typedef struct` and (to a lesser degree) `void*`, I'm going to assume that this is C code and C++ answers like "don't use raw pointers" do not apply.  Removing the [c++] tag.

Comment: *However, consider the following struct:* -- There is no "however".  The rules don't change.  If you happen to make your code into spaghetti with what is allocated, where it was allocated, etc.  that's a byproduct of you trying to manage dynamically allocated memory -- it doesn't change the simple fact that whatever you allocate, you deallocate.

Comment: *"Assume I've allocated memory for the Items struct and the Vector member contains, say, 3 items (of another struct Boxes)."* Instead of describing the code, show the code. Then we have something concrete to talk about. See [mcve].

Comment: It's pretty simple. 1 `malloc` requires 1 `free`. 2 `malloc` requires 2 `free`. 3 `malloc` requires 3 `free`. 4 `malloc` requires 4 `free`. ....

Comment: 1 allocation requires 1 free. You can have as many things pointing to it as you want, but 1 allocation requires 1 free. Read up on dangling pointers as well. Yes you only free things allocated with malloc or calloc.

Comment: Note that multiple paths through the code may require more than one call to `free` in the code. It's your job to make sure that the allocation passes through exactly one `free`. Typically you do this by making sure the number of code paths that `free` is as close to one as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute this:

```
Boxes* box1 = items->fruits[1];
```

Then `box1` and `items->fruits[1]` are the same pointer; they refer to the same object, which has one address in memory.

If you call `free(items->fruits[1])` then `items->fruits[1]` becomes an invalid pointer. Because `box1` is exactly that same pointer, it also becomes invalid.

If you know that that the memory management for `items->fruits[1]` is taken care of elsewhere, and you just want a shorter name for it some block of code, it can be often safe to create an alias for the object like `box1`.

You have to be absolutely sure that you don't continue to use `box1` at some point in the program where `box1` is still in the lexical scope (so accessing the variable *per se* is hunky dory), but some code has been executed which has already destroyed `items->fruits[1]`, to that `box1` has invisibly, stealthily become invalid.

If you have some code that has a `box1` alias, and it's possible that some function which it calls will destroy `items->fruits[1]` and replace that pointer with a new one. In that case you can pick up the new value:

```
Boxes *box1 = items->fruits[1];

maybe_replaces_items(items); // items->fruits[1] potentially overwritten

box1 = items->fruits[1]; // pick up latest fruits[1]
```

This kind of thing is a source of bugs.

You know that computing proverb that "there are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things"? Well, this is cache invalidation: `box1` is a cached copy of some pointer that has possibly gone invalid, and must be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

**man** [malloc/free](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)

> The  malloc() function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. ...

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), ...

- That being said, the address returned by `malloc` has to be passed later to `free`, nothing in between.
- Each `malloc` must be followed by a corresponding `free`.